# 'Upgrading' from XP to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, upgrade, migration, sysprep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade from XP Professional to Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/35059/upgrade-from-xp-professional-to-windows-7)
>   [XP to Windows 7 upgrade, WITHOUT reinstalling stuff](https://superuser.com/questions/156154/xp-to-windows-7-upgrade-without-reinstalling-stuff)

I need to upgrade a lot of PCs from XP to 7. I'm aware I can't do a straight upgrade and will need to do a fresh install. I need to take the following things into consideration:

- Given the number of machines, I need to automate the install somewhat.
- Each machine will need a suite of applications installed
- I want to keep the user profiles, My documents, files, bookmarks (FF & IE), printers, drive mappings..

I'm considering using sysprep - my understanding is that I can include required apps and the most common drive mappings?.

But my main question is how can I keep hold of the users' files, bookmarks, etc..? Is there a way I can create a DVD that will export all users' files and settings to a network drive, install 7 and then re-import the settings with a minimum of human interaction?

Any suggestions appreciated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [XP to Windows 7 upgrade, WITHOUT reinstalling stuff](http://superuser.com/questions/156154/xp-to-windows-7-upgrade-without-reinstalling-stuff) and/or [Upgrade from XP Professional to Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/35059/upgrade-from-xp-professional-to-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft you have [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) which as far as I am aware can be used to back up all personal files to CD, USB drive or even network share.

> Use Windows Easy Transfer to copy your files, photos, music, e-mail, settings, and more from a computer running Windows XP to a computer running Windows 7. You can transfer data using an Easy Transfer Cable, removable media, or across a network

You then simply use the Easy Transfer wizard built in to Windows 7 to import those settings and data.

Note though

> Windows Easy Transfer doesn't move your programs, only your files and settings. You'll need to reinstall your programs by hand after Windows 7 installation is complete. Windows Easy Transfer will provide you with a list of programs that you are currently using with Windows XP.

Microsoft have a neat guide [Upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7)

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more automated. Using WET would mean plugging in an external drive into each machine, too, as you can't store the exported profile details on a network share - only transfer direct from an XP machine to a Win 7 machine..

Comment: You can likely map a network drive, and then use WET to back up to that.  At least that works on Win7, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work in XP too.